# How to create sql file and write query dynamically in sql file using PHP?

Tags: php

I am creating .sql file dynamically and write create table query, but the query print in one line, but i need it something like

```
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE `tbl_demo` (
        `system_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
        `last_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
        `first_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
        `full_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
        `phone` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
        `ext` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
        `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
        `dept` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
        `site` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
        `room` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
        `job_title` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
        `image` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
        `url` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
        `active` varchar(200) NOT NULL
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";
```

Here is my code.

```
        <?php

        $content = file_get_contents('demo.csv');
        $table = 'demo';

        $exp = explode("\n", $content);

        echo '<pre>';

        $headers = explode(',', strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $exp[0])));

        $table_columns = array();
        foreach ($headers as $header) {
            $table_columns[] = '`' . $header . '`' . ' VARCHAR(255)';
        }
        $sql = 'CREATE TABLE ' . '`' . $table . '`' .  '(' . implode(',', $table_columns) . ') ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8';
        print_r($sql);


        $myfile = fopen("temp/demo.sql", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
        fwrite($myfile, $sql);
        fclose($myfile);
```

Any solution Appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried anything? Seems that it's enough to add newline characters where needed

Comment: Yes, i tried \n but it doesn't work, now i know where was the error

Comment: If you get some error it's good to include it in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the single quotes (') to double quotes (") in your php and at the end of the line put in backslash n (\n).
i.e.

```
$VarToFile = "This is my line\n";
$VarToFile .= "This is a new line\n";
```

Or try change

```
implode(',', $table_columns)
```

to

```
implode(",\n", $table_columns)
```